# How can I get column name by index with Bootstrap Datatables?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Ultimately, I am wanting to send my table's column sorting to the server so I can retrieve a sorted, paginated recordset from the database.  This line of code gets me on that path:

```
$("#results").DataTable().order();
```

However, it returns an array like this:

```
[[0,"asc"]]
```

I can't rely on a column index from a clientside array to order my dataset on the serverside.  What I need is an array like this:

```
[["Name","asc"],["HireDate","desc"]]
```

If I were to write an API like this, I'd make the column names accessible like so:

```
$("#results").DataTable().columns()[0].name;
$("#results").DataTable().columns(0).name;
```

Doesn't seem that the DataTable API is so straightforward, though.

Answer (score 0):

In your data table, you need to write the **name** parameter to the field if you want to retrieve the name in your API. Check my bellow code,

```
.DataTable({
 //rest code,
 "order": [
        [0, "asc"]
    ],
 //rest code,
 "columns": [
          { "data": "HireDate", name: "Date", },
 //rest columns
```

Here I set the name **Date** to the field **HireDate**.

And in my Api method,

```
string _ordByColumn = 
       GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(), 
                               "order[0].column");
string _ordColumnName = 
       GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(), "columns[" 
                                + _ordByColumn + "].name");
string _ordDirection = 
       GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(), 
                                "order[0].dir");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ordByColumn))
        {
            switch (_ordColumnName)
            {
                case "Date":
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(_ordDirection, "asc") == 0)
                        {
                            //retrieve data order by Date
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //retrieve data order by descending Date
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                 //rest cases and then default
                 default:
                     {
                        //retrieve data order by what ever you want
                        break;
                     }
              }
           }
```

And my GetQueryValueByName class bellow,

```
public static class GetQueryValueByName
{
    public static string Get(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _req, 
                             string key)
    {
        return _req.FirstOrDefault(ma => string.Compare(ma.Key, key) == 
                                   0).Value;
    }
}
```

You can fetch the query string as your way.